# Set django model instance field like dictionary

Tags: python, django, model

In django, we can update model instance field like:

```
from .models import Credentials
current_cre=Credentials.object.get(user=request.user)

current_cre.fb_name='Name'
current_cre.fb_pass='****'
current_cre.save()
```

Is there any way that I can do it like dictionary item:

```
current_cre['fb_name']='Name'
current_cre['fb_pass']='Pass'
```

So I can iterate the process like:

```
for field_name in List_Fields:
    current_cre[field_name]=request.POST[field_name]
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the inbuilt [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) for this, as

```
from .models import Credentials

current_cre = Credentials.object.get(user=request.user)
current_cre.__dict__['fb_name'] = "Name"
current_cre.__dict__['fb_pass'] = "****"
current_cre.save()
```

if `user` is a `unique` field, then you could try this also,

```
from .models import Credentials

my_dict = {"fb_name": "Name", "fb_pass": "****"}
current_cre = Credentials.object.filtert(user=request.user).update(**my_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
List_Fields = [(f.verbose_name, f.name) for f in Credentials._meta.get_fields()]

for field_name, value in List_Fields:
    current_cre[field_name]=request.POST[field_name]
```